# how do i add a title attribute to a panel (div) in the c# code behind file?

Tags: c#, .net

ASP.NET
C#

how do i add a title attribute to a panel (div) in the c# code behind file?

Answer (score 8):

Add a runat="server" attribute to your div, then you can access it like any other ASP.NET control.

markup:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

code-behind:

```
myDiv.Attributes["title"] = "some title";
```

Answer (score 4):

In your aspx page:

```
<asp:panel id="MyPanel" runat="server"></asp:panel>
```

In your codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyPanel.Attributes.Add("title", "A title for this div");
}
```